# Что это за оператор => в свойстве

Tags: c#

Что это за оператор => в свойстве

```
public int X { get => x; set => x = value; }
```

Comment: `оператор =>` заменяет ключевое слово `return`, можно использовать в свойствах, методах и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это геттер/сеттер с телом-выражением. Такой синтаксический сахар появился в C# с версии 7.0

По сути это более короткий способ записать код:

```
public int X 
{
    get
    {
        return x;
    }
    set 
    {
        x = value;
    }   
}
```

В C# 6.0 уже можно было объявлять методы и свойства только-для-чтения с телом-выражением ([Expression-bodied members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)). В седьмой версии идею распространили на другие члены класса.

Из C# Programming Guide ([Expression body definitions](http://Expression%20body%20definitions)):

> Starting with C# 7.0, both the get and the set accessor can be implemented as expression-bodied members. In this case, the get and set keywords must be present.

Ну и обоснование из предложения в Github ([Proposal: Expression bodied get and set methods](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7881)):

> However, when you need to fall back to writing a get and set method manually, it can be annoying that you're no longer allowed to use expression bodies.